# Should I use contracted forms in scientific presentations?

Tags: word-usage, pronunciation, slang, speech, contractions

In a scientific paper am I right in believing that one would write “it is” instead of “it’s”?

In a scientific presentation, would one use contracted forms like “it’s” instead of “it is” or is something like this too informal for a scientific conversation?

Comment: When in doubt:  use **it is**. Saying it that way, will keep your public speaking measured, not hurried. That's a different topic anyway.

Comment: Do you mean spoken or written in the slides? I wouldn’t use written contractions in a formal presentation. I would use them verbally, albeit inadvertently.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using obvious references are off-topic. Here, your institution's (or a general scientific English) style guide should be consulted.

Comment: "Asking whether you should use contractions in formal academic writing is sort of like asking whether you should wear a bathing suit to a party—it depends on the type of party. Is it a pool party or..." http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2015/12/contractions-in-formal-writing-whats-allowed-whats-not.html

Comment: What would Commander Data do?

Answer (score 2):

**Preamble**

Answering this question three months after it was posted, I wonder that it was not classified as subjective and therefore off-topic. My answer — which is directed at others that may have the same question rather than the original poster — gives advice that cannot help but be subjective to some extent. However I have tried to maek it both scientific, by quoting examples in support of my assertions, and suitable for SE ELU by focusing on the usage. In particular I challenge the assumptions of some other answers or comments regarding *actual usage of contractions in formal speech.* For this reason also, the answer assumes a native fluency with English.

**Scientific Papers**

The poster’s assertion that it is accepted style not to use contractions in scientific articles *is correct*. It can be verified by inspection of articles in one’s field using an electronic ‘search’ facility. To anticipate what follows, try searching for a ’ (smart apostrophe) in [this paper](http://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/100/14/8048.full.pdf) which I think is freely available. You can find two possessive examples (Briggs and King’s, McGrath and Solter’s) and one Irish surname (O’Brien), but no contractions.

Why?

Because contractions are used in speech for speed and ease of oral communication in sentences where there is no need for emphasis of the contracted phrase. In the written language these considerations do not apply.

**Scientific Oral Presentations**

What then should one do when making an oral presentation?

My advice  is to try to speak formally, *but naturally*. If you listen to experienced speakers you will find that they ***frequently use contractions***. Avoiding all contractions would be forced and sound unnatural. Nobody would [say](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_the_economy,_stupid):

> It is the economy, stupid!

However that’s politics. Let us take one of the most formal examples of a scientific lecture by one of the most formal (British) native-English speakers, Sir John Gurdon FRS, of Oxford (originally) and (now) Cambridge University, in his 2012 Nobel Prize lecture.  Here are a few examples you can find if you follow the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a99BxCtGOm4) to this:

> 15.16 “…**did not** work like this” *(No contraction)*
>
> 15.40 “But the nucleus **doesn’t** want to do that”  *(Contraction)*
>
> 15.56 “The cells **do not** contain…” *(No contraction)*
>
> 17.03 “…that **we’re** accustomed to” *(Contraction)*
>
> 17.08 “…**that’s** I **don’t** think scientifically of any great consequence” *(Contraction)*
>
> 18.07 “…whether **you’re** measuring…” *(Contraction)*
>
> 18.23 “More recently **there’s** this…” *(Contraction)*

He is talking very formally, but he’s talking naturally and using many contractions.

And the sentence above is contrived to illustrate how the use of contracted and non-contracted forms can be used didactically for emphasis in public speaking.

> He **is** talking very formally…

The spoken stress on the uncontracted “is” to confirm my previous assertion, despite the speaker’s use of contractions.

> …but **he’s** talking naturally

The contracted form is natural because the spoken stress would be on “naturally” and the uncontracted form would deflect from this.

**And by the way…**

…the author of the paper cited above is, of course, no other than Sir John Gurdon.

Answer (score -2):

The appropriateness of contractions in speech and writing is highly sensitive to context. I'd expect the slides, speech, and presentation style of a Nobel-prize-winning scientist to be very different from that of an undergraduate, for example. When presenting scientific results, you should look to consensus in the field or guidance from a superior. This means:

- If you're adding supplemental presentation slides to a research article, follow the style guide instructions of the journal of interest.
- If you're presenting in a class, ask your teacher/professor for their stylistic preference, if any.
- If you're representing your academic group, ask your advisor/PI.
- If you're representing your company, refer to the style guide of the organization or ask your supervisor.
- If it's just you (i.e., you're not receiving direct instruction from anyone—perhaps you're a group leader), then take guidance from the other presentations you see at that particular conference or meeting.